# PHP imagecreatefrompng losing color

Tags: imagecreatefrompng

I'm doing a simple load of an image using imagecreatefrompng.

The background of the image is #E5DDBB. Using the code below, it renders the image but the background is now #DED6AD.

http://www.letslogic.com/test.php contains the following:

```
<img src="images/skins/yoshi/0.png">

<img src="dyn_image.php">
```

dyn_image.php contains:

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatefrompng('images/skins/yoshi/0.png');

header("Content-Type: image/png");

imagepng($im);

?>
```

If you look at the two images that test.php shows, the images are different colours...

Comment: What version of GD and PHP are you using?

Comment: GD: bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
PHP: 5.2.17

Comment: Is it possible that the image has transparency?

Comment: Not that I can see...

http://letslogic.com/images/skins/yoshi/0.png

Comment: Is this the original image? Because the background is #DED6AD to me.

Comment: I see http://letslogic.com/images/shot.png

When I compare using colorpic, I see different colours.

Comment: So if the image you linked previously was not the resulting image, but the original image, can I have the original image?

Comment: http://letslogic.com/images/skins/yoshi/0.png is the original image - my screenshot is using the original image.

Comment: Still #DED6AD. So far it seems your verification of the original image's background color is incorrect.

Comment: Can you now see two different images in http://www.letslogic.com/test.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a color profile issue. Something to do with the image being of one color profile, whereas gd only lets you save your image in the one color profile it knows how to save images by which differs from the inputted image's, resulting in the colors looking different.

It seems you are going to need to use imagemagick to not have the colors changed. You should read these:

http://www.zenphoto.org/support/topic.php?id=3582

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-image/viewthread/1085

Comment: Yep, "GD, ignores color profiles" as explained in http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/57/A-Tale-of-Two-Images.aspx